# Pivoting a field based on date range in table B that is >= date range in table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot a row into columns that are based on formatted dates 'yyyy-MMM' and while this works as expected for a current month period, it fails to work for future months and I cannot figure out how to fix this and would greatly appreciate any feedback on this.

Here's a little bit of background:
I have purchased quantity coming from a Vendor summary table that includes information about a contract such as contract type, quantity, lot number, creation date formatted into 'yyyy-MMM' as the actual date does not matter for this purpose.

Remaining Quantity is another field coming from an item ledger entry table which is essentially summing up all kinds of entries based on lot number.

Consumed Quantity is what I am trying to pivot based on the month it was consumed and is also coming from the item ledger entries with an entry type filter

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
SELECT VS.[Vendor Name], VS.[Vendor No_] AS 'Vendor_No', VS.[Date] AS 'Date', 
SUM(VS.Quantity) AS 'Contracted_Quantity',
SUM(CQ.Consumed_Qty*-1) AS 'Consumed_Qty',
SUM(RQ.Remaining_Qty) AS Remaining_Qty,
'Contract Type' = 
CASE 
  WHEN VS.[Contract Type] = 1 THEN 'CONTRACT A'
  WHEN VS.[Contract Type] = 2 THEN 'CONTRACT B'
  ELSE 'OTHERS'
  END 
FROM
(SELECT [Document No_],[Vendor No_],[Lot No_],FORMAT([Date Created], 'yyyy-MMM') AS 'Date'
      ,[Purch_ Contract No_],[Contract Type],[Quantity] FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Volume Summary]) VS

/*to identify remaining quantity by lot (Lot no. is included in my VS alias statement)*/
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Lot No_] ,SUM([Remaining Quantity]) AS Remaining_Qty FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry]
  GROUP BY [Lot No_]) RQ on RQ.[Lot No_] = VS.[Lot No_]

/*to identify consumed volume, if consumption is in future month compared to purchase month, it doesn't populate, this is where I believe the problem is*/
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Lot No_],FORMAT([Posting Date], 'yyyy-MMM') AS 'Date',SUM([Quantity]) AS Consumed_Qty
FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry]
WHERE [Entry Type] = '5' 
GROUP BY [Lot No_], Format([Posting Date], 'yyyy-MMM')) CQ on CQ.[Lot No_] = VS.[Lot No_] and CQ.Date >= VS.[Date]

GROUP BY VS.[Vendor Name], FORMAT(VS.[Date Created],'yyyy-MMM'), PT.[Contract Type], VS.[Vendor No_]
) cs 
PIVOT
(
 SUM(Consumed_Qty)
  for Date in ([2021-Sep], [2021-Oct], [2021-Nov])
  ) pvt
```

RESULT (Only showing partially):

[image]

As you can see, the second ABC Technology record shows a consumption in 2021-Oct which is accurate, however, based on that contracted amount purchased also in 2021-Oct, and what is remaining in that record, the consumption needs to be 9,373 and is short (383) compared to the 8,990 it is accurately displaying in 2021-Oct. In this case the 383 actual consumption is falling in 2021-Nov, however, my code doesn't seem to pick that up.

This is the exact case in both Zebra technologies records as well, where the remaining is 0 which would mean it has been entirely consumed, however, since the purchase contract dates for both of them are in 2021-Sep and the consumption is in the future month 2021-Oct, the SQL script doesn't pick that up.

I'd appreciate any guidance to help fix this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply sample data and expected output *as text* not images. How does `[Lot No_]` factor in, why are you joining on it? We can't see any of this from the information you have provided. `EOMONTH(VS.[Date Created])` might be better performance (and possibly more accurate) than `FORMAT(VS.[Date Created],'yyyy-MMM')`.

Comment: Lot_No is what shows where the inventory sits, Soon as there is a purchase of x quantity, this is where the total quantity purchased is assigned to. The item ledger entries against this lot number when summed up is what shows our total consumption quantity related to each lot. the problem is the date of purchase does not matter for my purpose, the goal is to identify how much quantity was consumed month over month, which is why I formatted date in yyyy-MMM format and added a join with a >= purchase date in addition to the lot number, however, it does not recognize consumptions > purchase date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pivoting based on the VS.[Date] which is when the Lot was purchased, not when it was consumed. The last three columns will only show numbers when the items were purchased AND consumed in the SAME month.

Instead of pivoting the whole dataset, move the pivot into the third subquery. This simplifies the query by getting the Lot details including the Contracted_Qty and Remaining_Qty first and then join to the third subquery which is the pivoted set of Consumed_Qty by Lot by the three months.

```
SELECT VS.[Vendor Name], VS.[Vendor No_] AS 'Vendor_No',
VS.[Contracted_Quantity],
RQ.Remaining_Qty AS Remaining_Quantity,
'Contract Type' = 
CASE 
  WHEN VS.[Contract Type] = 1 THEN 'CONTRACT A'
  WHEN VS.[Contract Type] = 2 THEN 'CONTRACT B'
  ELSE 'OTHERS'
  END,
CQ.[2021-Sep], CQ.[2021-Oct], CQ.[2021-Nov]

FROM
    (
    /* List of Lots with details */
    SELECT 
        [Document No_],[Vendor No_],[Lot No_], [Purch_ Contract No_],[Contract Type],[Quantity] AS [Contracted_Quantity]
    FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Volume Summary]
    ) VS

    /* Remaining Quantity for each Lot */
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [Lot No_] , SUM([Remaining Quantity]) AS Remaining_Quantity 
        FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry]
        GROUP BY [Lot No_]
        ) RQ on RQ.[Lot No_] = VS.[Lot No_]

    /* Consumed Quantity per Lot for three months*/
    LEFT JOIN (

        SELECT [Lot No_], [2021-Sep], [2021-Oct], [2021-Nov]
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT [Lot No_], FORMAT([Posting Date], 'yyyy-MMM') AS 'Date', SUM([Quantity]) AS Consumed_Qty
        FROM [A].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry]
        WHERE [Entry Type] = '5' 
        GROUP BY [Lot No_], Format([Posting Date], 'yyyy-MMM')
        ) AS src
        PIVOT
        (
         SUM(Consumed_Qty)
          for [Date] in ([2021-Sep], [2021-Oct], [2021-Nov])
          ) pvt

        ) CQ on CQ.[Lot No_] = VS.[Lot No_]
;
```

I can't test this query without the data but it should be very close.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I am using SUM(remaining) is because the item ledger entry table has multiple entry types, purchase, adjustments, consumption. The sum of all entry types for each lot number is what gets me to remaining qty and it does tie out to my lot inventory ledger. however, when I now use CQ.Date in the pivot and remove the >= date join on CQ, it now duplicates the purchase record for each month's consumption making the purchased total by lot incorrect now. what other data could I provide to help explain my problem better? much appreciate your time and help with this

Comment: The next adjustment would be to move the pivot into the third sub query.  Instead of pivoting the whole dataset, get the Lot details including the Contracted_Qty and Remaining_Qty and then join to the third subquery which is the pivoted set of Consumed_Qty by Lot by the three months.

Comment: I’m still curious how you can get quantity remaining by summing some number. Can you provide some sample data to demonstrate?

Comment: Never mind on the quantity remaining. I just realized your ledger table must record every number in two columns. Remaining Quantity is either a positive or negative number depending on the entry type. Summing this would yield the quantity remaining. The column name threw me off.

Comment: Yep that is correct! Thats how the ledger table records each entry.

Comment: thats a good idea! I will try moving the pivot into the subquery, you were right about the first part though, I had my pivot based on purchase date instead of the consumption date, and next I grouped by the lot no. which seemed to have fixed the issue. but i like the idea of moving the pivot to the third subquery, will keep you posted! Thanks

Comment: Answer updated based on feedback in comments